# Remove PhpStorm new version`s background

Tags: phpstorm

How to remove this new PhpStorm texture from this background?

[image: PHP Storm Screenshot]

I searched everywhere and could not find it! I like it plain gray as it was before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish I can have it .... it 's not here on my computer.... On a serious note -- it most likely was "installed" by one of the plugins you have got there. Anyway: you can modify/remove it via `Ctrl+Shift+A` and then look for `Set Background Image`.

Comment: Oh great I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Ctrl+Shift+A` and then look for `Set Background Image`

[image]

2. Click the `Frame` field

[image]

3. Set opacity to zero and hit `Ok`

[image]

4. This is how it looks

[image]